# Using a System.Drawing.Image as the centered part of a larger image?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, system.drawing.imaging

I have a System.Drawing.Image that I would like to use as the centered portion for a new, larger image.  I’m given the dimensions of the (always) larger image and the idea is to make that image all white and overlay its center with the first image.  Is there a way to do this using GDI+?  Some combination of TextureBrush and the Graphic class perhaps?  I’m open to suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of similar questions, here's one that I think will show you the basics:

[How could I position multiple transparent PNGs onto a JPG using c# and asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389538/how-could-i-position-multiple-transparent-pngs-onto-a-jpg-using-c-and-asp-net)